# Cannot retrieve the CVE-ID for the windows updates

Tags: c++, com, windows-update

I am writing the code using windows update agent apis, i am getting all the information except for the CVE-ID's associated with that update. I know that update type can be bundle, i have also tried to extract the updates for the individual updates in the bundle, but i am unable to get the CVE-ID's.
I have tried using my code, to get the updates from the microsoft server and the local WSUS, but in both the cases i am unable to get the CVE_ID's.
Following is the code snippet to get the cveIds;

```
hrRes = pIUpdate2->get_CveIDs(&pIStrCollCveIds);
if (FAILED(hrRes))
{
pIUpdate2->Release();
return FALSE;
}

hrRes = pIStrCollCveIds->get_Count(&lCount);
if (FAILED(hrRes))
{
pIUpdate2->Release();
pIStrCollCveIds->Release();

return FALSE;
}
```

I get lCount as 0, every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... at last, i found that, CVE-ID field is optional and microsoft does not provide the CVE-ID information in their software packages.. Hence cannot be retrieved using the apis.

This info help others, so posted it..